# Firebase push to be ordered

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

When I push data to firebase it gives random string to a child, I want the push to be numbered or ordered

Values to be ordered when pushing in firebase.

I want to use the rules and google language in firebase to do this task.

Comment: Keys generated by Firebase Realtime Database's `push` function should be ordered already. IDs generated by Firestore's `add`/`addDoc`/`addDocument` functions are not ordered (by design). Can you edit your question to show which of these are you are using?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.